# $\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_C S_k(z)\,dz=\int_C f(z)\,dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to understand the proof of the following theorem in my textbook.

Theorem: Suppose that $\{S_k(z)\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions defined on a set T containing the contour C. If $\{S_k(z)\}$ converges uniformly to $f(z)$ on the set T, then

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_C S_k(z)dz=\int_C f(z)dz$$

Proof: Let $\epsilon>0$ and L equal the length of the contour C. Because $\{S_k(z)\}$ converges uniformly to $f(z)$, there exists an $N_\epsilon$ so that $n\ge N_\epsilon$ implies that

$$|S_n(z)-f(z)|<\frac{\epsilon}{L}$$

for all $z\in T$. Then the author says

$$ M=\text{Max}_{z\in C}|S_n(z)-f(z)|<\frac{
\epsilon}{L}\qquad\text{for all}\qquad n\ge N_\epsilon$$

Now, this is where I am stuck. Why is this last statement true?

For example, consider the set $\{1-1/n: n\in \mathbb N\}$. It's true that

$$1-\frac1n<1\qquad\text{for all}\qquad n\in\mathbb N$$

but the set $\{1-1/n: n\in \mathbb N\}$ does not have a maximum value.

The reason the author uses this statement is because he will use the property

$$\left|\int_C f(z) dz\right|\le ML$$

to finish with

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\left|\int_C S_k(z)ds-\int_Cf(z)dz\right|&=&\left|\int_C[S_k(z)-f(z)]dz\right|\\
\left|\int_C S_k(z)ds-\int_Cf(z)dz\right|&\le&ML\\
\left|\int_C S_k(z)ds-\int_Cf(z)dz\right|&<&\frac{\epsilon}{L}\cdot L\\
\left|\int_C S_k(z)ds-\int_Cf(z)dz\right|&<&\epsilon
\end{array}
$$

proving that

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_CS_k(z)\,dz=\int_C f(z)dz$$

**Update:**  We define $z(t)=x(t)+iy(t)$ on the interval $a\le t\le b$. Note that the interval $[a,b]=\{t:a\le t\le b\}$ is compact. Now, if $z'(t)$ is continuous and nonzero on the interval $[a,b]$, then we have what is called a smooth curve, or a contour.

Now two facts I reviewed:

1. A compact set contains its supremum and infimum.
2. If $f$ is a continuous function then the image of a compact set is a compact set.

Now, because $\{S_n(z)\}$ is a set of continuous functions that converge uniformly to $f(z)$, this means that $f(z)$ is continuous, which means that $S_n(z)-f(z)$ is also a continuous function for all $n$. This in turn means that $|S_n(z)-f(z)|$ is also a continuous function, which will map the interval $[a,b]$ onto a compact set, the set

$$\{|S_n(z)-f(z)|: z\in C\}$$

Because this set is compact, it contains its maximum (the supremum). Therefore, there exists an $M$ so that

$$|S_n(z)-f(z)|\le M\qquad\text{for all}\qquad n\ge N_\epsilon$$

But because $M$lies in the set $\{|S_n(z)-f(z)|: z\in C\}$ and the elements

$$ |S_n(z)-f(z)|<\frac{\epsilon}{L}\qquad\text{for all}\qquad n\ge N_\epsilon$$

this means that

$$M<\frac{\epsilon}{L}$$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Passing to the maximum, in the general case the strict inequality can become non-strict, so you will end up with $\le \epsilon$ instead of $<\epsilon$ at the end, which is still good enough. However, here by compactness and continuity all functions attain their maximum on $C$ and this way you still get the strict inequality.

Comment: First, it doesn't matter, the previous line shows that the quantity has an upper bound $\epsilon \over L$ so that is sufficient for the proof. Second, the function $z \mapsto |S_n(z)-f(z)|$ is continuous and the range of the contour $C$ is compact, hence a $\max $ exists.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for your help. See my update.

Comment: @Lukas Geyer 4 Thanks for your help. See my update.